# Refresh the fragment after Camera Intent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, camera

I am calling the Camera Intent from one of the fragments to save the image into gallery. The photo is taken and the image also gets saved in the gallery. I also have an adapter which gets all the images stored in the gallery into my application using GridView. So after taking the photo from the Camera Intent, I have to go back to another fragment and come back to see my photo refreshed in the GridView. So basically, I want to refresh the fragment once I am back from the Camera Intent.

Here is the structure. I have a fragment called GalleryHomeFragment, from which I click a button and go to GalleryFragment. From there, I call the Camera Intent. My requirement is to refresh the GalleryFragment, once I come back from taking the picture, to see the pictures in my folders.

Here is what I have tried so far. Posting the necessary code.

**GalleryFragment.java**

```
cameraButton = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.cameraBtn);

    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    });

    //gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    gv_folder = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gv_folder);
    gv_folder.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), PhotosActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("value",i);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) && (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }else {
        Log.e("Else","Else");
        fn_imagespath();
    }
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    return view;
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {photoFile = createImageFile();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            Context context = getContext();
            CharSequence text = "Photo cannot be stored.";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Context context = getContext();
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                    "com.example.projectga.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);

        }else{
            Context context = getContext();
            CharSequence text = "Attention! Required to take picture!!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}

public void createFolder(){
    if (!directory.exists()){
        directory.mkdirs();
    }

}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    createFolder();
    // Create an image file name
    Context context = getContext();
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = projectName + "_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    addImageToGallery(image, context);

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getPath();
    return image;
}

public static void addImageToGallery(File image, final Context context) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, image.toString());

    context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

}

 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    search = menu.add("search").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search_green_24dp).setShowAsActionFlags(1);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

public ArrayList<Model_images> fn_imagespath() {
    al_images.clear();

    int int_position = 0;
    Uri uri;
    Cursor cursor;
    int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;

    String absolutePathOfImage = null;
    uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};

    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
    cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy + " DESC");

    column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
    column_index_folder_name = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
        Log.e("Column", absolutePathOfImage);
        Log.e("Folder", cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));

        for (int i = 0; i < al_images.size(); i++) {
            if (al_images.get(i).getStr_folder().equals(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name))) {
                boolean_folder = true;
                int_position = i;
                break;
            } else {
                boolean_folder = false;
            }
        }

        if (boolean_folder) {

            ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
            al_path.addAll(al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath());
            al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
            al_images.get(int_position).setAl_imagepath(al_path);

        } else {
            ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
            al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
            Model_images obj_model = new Model_images();
            obj_model.setStr_folder(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));
            obj_model.setAl_imagepath(al_path);
            al_images.add(obj_model);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < al_images.size(); i++) {
        Log.e("FOLDER", al_images.get(i).getStr_folder());
        for (int j = 0; j < al_images.get(i).getAl_imagepath().size(); j++) {
            Log.e("FILE", al_images.get(i).getAl_imagepath().get(j));
        }
    }
    obj_adapter = new Adapter_PhotosFolder(getContext(),al_images);
    gv_folder.setAdapter(obj_adapter);
    return al_images;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PERMISSIONS: {
            for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    fn_imagespath();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "The app was not allowed to read or write to your storage. Hence, it cannot function properly. Please consider granting it this permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**GridViewAdapter.java**

```
Context context;
ViewHolder viewHolder;
ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();
int int_position;


public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu,int int_position) {
    super(context, R.layout.adapter_photosfolder, al_menu);
    this.al_menu = al_menu;
    this.context = context;
    this.int_position = int_position;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    Log.e("ADAPTER LIST SIZE", al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size() + "");
    return al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    if (al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size() > 0) {
        return al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size();
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_photosfolder, parent, false);
        viewHolder.tv_foldern = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder);
        viewHolder.tv_foldersize = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder2);
        viewHolder.iv_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.tv_foldern.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    viewHolder.tv_foldersize.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    Glide.with(context).load("file://" + al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position))
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .into(viewHolder.iv_image);


    return convertView;

}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_foldern, tv_foldersize;
    ImageView iv_image;
}
}
```

**Adapter_PhotosFolder.java**

```
 Context context;
ViewHolder viewHolder;
ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();
int int_position;


public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu,int int_position) {
    super(context, R.layout.adapter_photosfolder, al_menu);
    this.al_menu = al_menu;
    this.context = context;
    this.int_position = int_position;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    Log.e("ADAPTER LIST SIZE", al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size() + "");
    return al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    if (al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size() > 0) {
        return al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size();
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_photosfolder, parent, false);
        viewHolder.tv_foldern = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder);
        viewHolder.tv_foldersize = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder2);
        viewHolder.iv_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.tv_foldern.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    viewHolder.tv_foldersize.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    Glide.with(context).load("file://" + al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position))
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .into(viewHolder.iv_image);


    return convertView;

}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_foldern, tv_foldersize;
    ImageView iv_image;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was so stupid and why I don't know it took me so long to figure out the answer.

I did this by restarting the fragment in the onActivityResult() like this.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Fragment galleryFragment = new GalleryFragment();
       FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
       fm.popBackStack();
       FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
       ft.replace(R.id.container_gaFragments, galleryFragment);
       ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
       ft.addToBackStack(null);
       ft.commit();
    }
}
```

So each time when the result of activity is a success, I refresh the fragment to the galleryFragment and it works perfect.